# Linker command failed iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've just upadted my xCode to the latest version and I've downloaded the the sample projects from you can get from the guys making the Estimote iBeacons. However, when I try to build their sample project I get the following error:

> (null): Directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Users/com/Desktop/iOS-SDK-master/NotificationDemo/../../../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EstimoteBLE-fciknfmtjexyisdvrlnpfgdjgsck/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos"'
>
> (null): Directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Users/soluis27mac/Desktop/iOS-SDK-master/NotificationDemo/../SDK"'
>
> (null): Directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/Gacek/Documents/Programowanie/iOS/Estimote/publicEstimoteSDK/iOS-SDK/SDK'
>
> (null): Library not found for -lEstimoteBLE
>
> (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I've googled around for this and a lot of it seems to tell me I need to do something with my build options. However, all of the things I have tried ([like this website for example](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/04/09/library-not-found-tip-for-iphone-developers)) still result in the same error.

I have simply tried creating a new project and re-writing the code again following the the installation instructions they give. However, this results in more errors as such:

> (null): Ignoring file
>   /Users/comp/Desktop/iOS-SDK-master/SDK/libEstimoteBLE.a,
>   missing required architecture i386 in file
>   /Users/comp/Desktop/iOS-SDK-master/SDK/libEstimoteBLE.a (2
>   slices)
>
> (null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BeaconManager", referenced from:
>
> (null): Objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>
> (null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I know this can be a fairly common problem when downloading sample projects off the internet, but can anyone give some other suggestions as to what I can try to beat this error. I'm still fairly new to the world of iOS development and xCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*missing required architecture i386* means that the library is not build for simulator i.e. i386 architecture. You need to ask the owner of the library to provide simulator built .a file as well. Till then you can build your code for iOS device and check if builds.

Hope that helps!